# How to filter list data in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to make a simple demonstration of Web scraping using Beautiful Soup. I made a list of clothing and wanted to filter out the ones that were purple. I tried to write an if statement for this but it was completely ignored. Any help is appreciated.

This is the Html List and the python code.

Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ('local.html', 'r') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    clothingdiv = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'clothing')

for element in clothingdiv:
    text = element.find_all('li')
    if 'Purple' not in text:
        print(text)
```

Html:

```
    <div class="clothing">
        <li>Purple Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>Orange Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>Red Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>White Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>Purple Hoodie: $15</li>
        <li>Orange Hoodie: $15</li>
        <li>Red Hoodie: $15</li>
        <li>Purple Jacket: $20</li>
        <li>Orange Jacket: $20</li>
        <li>Red Jacket: $20</li>
        <li>White Jacket: $20</li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select all `<li>` tags under `class="clothing"` and check if `Purple` is not inside the text:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
    <div class="clothing">
        <li>Purple Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>Orange Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>Red Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>White Shirt: $10</li>
        <li>Purple Hoodie: $15</li>
        <li>Orange Hoodie: $15</li>
        <li>Red Hoodie: $15</li>
        <li>Purple Jacket: $20</li>
        <li>Orange Jacket: $20</li>
        <li>Red Jacket: $20</li>
        <li>White Jacket: $20</li>
    </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

for li in soup.select(".clothing li"):
    if "Purple" not in li.text:
        print(li.text)
```

Prints:

```
Orange Shirt: $10
Red Shirt: $10
White Shirt: $10
Orange Hoodie: $15
Red Hoodie: $15
Orange Jacket: $20
Red Jacket: $20
White Jacket: $20
```

---

OR: You can use more advanced CSS selector:

```py
for li in soup.select(".clothing li:not(:-soup-contains(Purple))"):
    print(li.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The `text` variable contains a list of BeautifulSoup Tag objects, not plain text. So, when you use the `if 'Purple' not in text` statement, you are checking if the string 'Purple' is present in the list of Tag objects, which will always evaluate to True.

## Solution

Extract the text from tags before the if statement. Here is your code but updated to get the text of tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('local.html', 'r') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    clothingdiv = soup.find_all('div', class_='clothing')

for element in clothingdiv:
    items = element.find_all('li')
    for item in items:
        text = item.get_text()
        if 'Purple' in text:
            print(text)
```